# React check the elements of an array for a conditional display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to check if the value of my element appears in
an array if it is the case I give it the class
another class.

this is to make a map from another object array

How to check in the whole table if
Is there the value I want?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  
  
  class Dbz extends React.Component {
  
     constructor(props) { 
           super(props)
           
           This.state = {
           
              sayien = ['goku','vegeta','broly']
              warrioz = [
                          { name:goku
                            power: 1500
                            },
                         { name: yamcha
                            power: 150
                            },
                         { name: cell
                            power: 2500
                            },
                         ]
          
           }
     }
     
   
     render(){
     
         return(
      

     <div>   
       { this.state.warrioz.map((data) => {
 
          return (  
         <div className={this.state.sayien === data.name ? "sayien" :"nosayien"}>
            <p>{data.name} </p>
         </div>
            })}

     </div>
         
         )
        
     }
  
  
  
       }
       
       
   export default Dbz
```

Comment: `This.state` doesn't look like a valid syntax and also what is `data.name` here?

Comment: I just changed to make it clearer, do you have any idea what I could in this example bro?

Comment: You are still using `data.name` here `className={this.state.sayien === data.name ? "sayien" :"nosayien"}` but `data` is not declared anywhere?

Comment: Things @palaѕн mentioned are all still valid. I can't see how your edit has changed anything.

Comment: here is all the pieces of the puzzle it is an arraymap I simplified because sinan the site of request to write more text to balance with the code

Answer (score 1):

You can see if data.name is included in your state. But the question remains, where is data coming from?

```
<div className={this.state.sayien.includes(data.name) ? "sayien" :"nosayien"}>
    <p>goku </p>
</div>
```

If you are curious here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to the mdn doc for includes.